# Fedex custom packing modules

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce on D7, with the fedex shipping module, and all is well except the packaging algorithm is not advanced enough...

**Current Functionality**
Currently, you set one default box size in the fedex module config, and it uses that as a base unit of measure to determine how many of those boxes are needed to fit the volume of the order.

**The Problem**
The current method is kinda close, except now they want to have several box sizes, and the estimates are all over the place, usually way to high for large orders.

**Fedex module says...**
... you can create custom modules for more advanced calculation rules.

Quote:

> *More complex logic involving multiple package sizes, weights, and void space can be implemented via custom modules.*

**So, how?**
I can't find any examples of what this module would look like. I would be happy with just a barebones boilerplate module for this, or a tutorial, or best case someone elses functional module.